# How can I heal the most health while outside of the world border?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While outside the world border, I take tons of damage and would like to find a way to heal more than my previous solution.

I am using world border as a function in my minigame and being out of world border is part of the minigame as world border size will shrink to 0 forcing players to heal up.

My way to survive being outside the border currently is to use Lingering Potions of Healing 2. This way was still not fast enough and I died.

Here is the world border settings:

```
/worldborder damage buffer 0
/worldborder damage amount 17.5
/worldborder center ~10 ~10
/worldborder set 10
```

Comment: Don't go outside the world border?

Comment: @Ben I am making something that involves surviving the world border. Its more like a don't go out the world border, you will have to survive the world border because I will make it shrink to 0.

Comment: fair enough, it might be worthwhile adding that to your post. Normally the point of the world border is to *stop* people from going too far, and therefore save the server from having to load too much all at once.